# jquery selector missing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to highlight any element that has a class that starts with `a_slot_` but doesn't end with `pink` or `green` in any of the class names. In this example the third element I feel like should be highlighted because it has class `a_slot_orange` and the other class doesn't contain `pink` or `green`.

Why isn't the third element highlighted (but the last is)? How do I highlight the third with the others?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[class^='a_slot_']").each(function(i,v){
     if(!$(this).attr('class').includes('green') && !$(this).attr('class').includes('pink')){
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
     }
  });
  // also don't work....have the same result
  //$("[class^='a_slot_']:not([class$='green'],[class$='pink'])").css('background-color', 'red');
  //$("[class^='a_slot_']").not("[class$='green'],[class$='pink']").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class='a_slot a_slot_green'>Green</p>
<p class='a_slot a_slot_pink'>Pink</p>
<p class='a_slot a_slot_orange'>Orange (shouldn't I be highlighed too?)</p>
<p class='a_slot_green'>Green</p>
<p class='a_slot_pink'>Pink</p>
<p class='a_slot_orange'>Orange</p>
<p class='a_slot_4'>4</p>
<p class='a_slot_16'>16</p>
<p class='a_slot_16 other_class'>16</p>
<p class='a_slot_orange other_class'>Orange</p>
```

Comment: The first 3 paragraphs don't start with a_slot_

Comment: You probably want to use `$("[class*='a_slot_']")` .

Comment: @Gerard I know but the second class does

Comment: @depperm but you're using the attribute starts with selector

Comment: @billyonecan I thought the order of classes didn't matter

Comment: of course it does. the attribute in this case is class, the value of which is just a string. the selector doesn't check what each class starts with, it checks what the value starts with - [docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your selector `[class^='a_slot_']` you only select elements whose class attribute starts with that string so you wont select first three elements so you can change that to `[class^='a_slot']` and after that you can split class attribute for each element and use `some()` to find match.

```js
$("[class^='a_slot']").each(function(i, v) {
  var cls = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')
  var check = cls.some(function(e) {
    return e.startsWith('a_slot_') && !e.endsWith('green') && !e.endsWith('pink')
  })
  if (check) $(this).css('background', 'red')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='a_slot a_slot_green'>Green</p>
<p class='a_slot a_slot_pink'>Pink</p>
<p class='a_slot a_slot_orange'>Orange (shouldn't I be highlighed too?)</p>
<p class='a_slot_green'>Green</p>
<p class='a_slot_pink'>Pink</p>
<p class='a_slot_orange'>Orange</p>
<p class='a_slot_4'>4</p>
<p class='a_slot_16'>16</p>
<p class='a_slot_16 other_class'>16</p>
<p class='a_slot_orange other_class'>Orange</p>
```

Comment: You can also just use two attribute selectors, which is probably more efficient (and can be ported to CSS). See the duplicate link.

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
$("[class^='a_slot_']")
```

you select only elements that **starts** with `a_slot_`, but the third element is start with `a_slot` (without the following `_`).

For that you should use `$("[class*='a_slot_']")`

Answer (score 1):

you can use **[jQuery.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** for that

```
$("[class^='a_slot']").filter(
     function(){
      var matches = $(this).attr('class').match(/pink|green/g);
           return !matches;
     }
).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Ah, yes as others pointed out your selector is too greedy I've removed the underscore

https://jsfiddle.net/py89zr5y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this because ^ indicates start of string.

```
<p class='a_slot_orange a_slot'>Orange (shouldn't I be highlighed too?)</p>
```